# Getting ExpatParser$ParseException?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml code:

```
  <CUELEARN>
    <RESULT_RANK>1</RESULT_RANK>
    <RESULT_TOTAL>1</RESULT_TOTAL>
    <HIGHEST_MARKS>0</HIGHEST_MARKS>
  </CUELEARN>
```

But when I use my method to parse this shows an exception ExpatParser$ParseException. The method is working with all other xml but this one.The log shows:

```
  org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: syntax error
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Add the XML declaration to the top of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```